# MySQL (ADO.NET) Giving 'No Database Selected' Error when database is indeed selected

Tags: c#, mysql, ado.net, mysql.data

Using ADO.NET with the MySql Connector (MySql.Data) driver,  I open a new, non-pooled query (no initial catalog/database is specified in connection string) and issue the following query:

```
ALTER TABLE `public`.`table2` 
ADD CONSTRAINT `fk_table2_table1`
FOREIGN KEY (`table1_id`) REFERENCES `table1` (`id`);
```

The structure of the two tables is as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE `public`.`table1`
(
    id int primary key
);

CREATE TABLE `public`.`table2`
(
    id int primary key,
    table1_id int
);
```

The ALTER TABLE query causes the following exception:

MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException (0x80004005): No database selected

However, with the same setup, if I run the ALTER TABLE query using the mysql command line tool (and several other MySQL clients) I get no such error.

Does anyone have suggestions to things I can look into.  I'm currently thinking this is an issue with the MySql Connector (MySql.Data) driver, however, I could easily be wrong here.

**Update:**

We are not able to reproduce this with a minimally viable repro.  It is likely, the issue lies somewhere in our own code and not in the driver.

**Another update:**
We were actually able to successfully reproduce this using just the mysql command line tool.  It requires Mysql 5.6.34 (won't repro in many other versions I tested including 5.6.41).  Also, we reproduced in AWS RDS but not sure if that is required.  In order to reproduce perform the following steps:

1) Fresh database install
2) login via mysql command line tool
3) create two tables

> create schema public;
>   create table public.table1( id int primary key);
>   create table public.table2(id int primary key, table1_id int);
>   alter table `public`.`table2` add foreign key `fk_name` (`table1_id`) REFERENCES `table1`(`id`);

The final command results in the error:

ERROR 1046 (3D000): No database selected

Comment: Check your connection string first

Comment: But you haven't shown your connection string, how could we tell

Comment: Have you tried this code with https://www.nuget.org/packages/MySqlConnector/? If that works, it's almost certainly a bug in Oracle's MySQL Connector/NET (i.e., MySql.Data). You could report it at https://bugs.mysql.com/.

Comment: I can't reproduce any exception with MySql.Data using the SQL statement you've provided; can you provide more specific code that demonstrates the problem?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: Based on the updates to the question, I recommend including a database in the connection string, even if it's the wrong one. As long as that database exists on the server and you have connection privileges, you can still reference other databases.

Comment: folks, repro with mysql command line has been posted.  note: this repro happens on mysql 5.6.34 on RDS.  It does not happen on 5.6.41 so it was likely fixed in some minor version.  Unsure if it will repro outside of RDS.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn that unfortunately won't work for us.  we have instead modified the ALTER TABLE statement to place a USE directly before it.  Of course, for customers on version of mysql after 5.6.34 this is a non-issue in the first place.